# Flutter add TertiaryAnimation to buildTransitions in Route<T>

Tags: flutter, animation, routes

Extending Flutter's `Route<T>` class provides a `buildTransitions` method.

This method provides two `Animation<double>` properties `animation` and `secondaryAnimation`. animation is the `Animation<double>` of the top most routes entry animation, secondaryAnimation is the animation the `Animation<double>` of the next route's entry animation providing an animated value that can be used for an outbound animation for this route.

Can a **tertiaryAnimation** be added that would allow this route to receive an `Animation<double>` of it's effective grandchild in the route stack.

```
@override
  Widget buildTransitions(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Animation<double> tertiaryAnimation, // --> adding this
    Widget child,
  ) {  
...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Dart doesn't support methods overloading (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1741), so you must find a workaround to achieve your goal

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi Thanks, I have achieved this by running my own state on top of the navigator to track the index of each route and sign the controllers chronologically in reverse but it obviously adds unnecessary duplication of state already stored by Navigator but not accessible in the API (at least directly).